# Fimfiction.net story involving Discord cleaning up after a magical contract running amok?

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

I'm trying to find a https://www.fimfiction.net/ story involving Discord cleaning up after a magical contract running amok, with the help of some lawyer or accountant or some such person.

I think it starts like, "Canterloters were used to a lot of things" and had some lines about how a magical incident is evaluated by who arrives to handle it, in order of severity, going from the Royal Guard, the Elements of Harmony, or in this case, Discord.

The contract is mentioned as magically self-amending, or something of that sort, and that causes problems when it tries to compensate for the death of one party or another, and that this isn't the first time that Discord's had to deal with such a creation.

I think it was located in an anthology of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. It was an anthology.

https://www.fimfiction.net/story/346142/10/a-cavalcade-of-cards/after-the-pact

> If the only emergency responder was an earth pony janitor with no tools, everything would be back to normal by the time you blinked. If they showed up with a toolbox, it might be worth having an extended lunch. An out-of-town janitor meant several hours, a team meant a day, and then it started getting interesting.

You might've missed it due to not getting the terms exactly right. You used "self-amending" where it should've been "self-renewing" or just "annotate". "Amend" appears nowhere in the story.

And how Google seems to not have indexed that story, with the only copy detectable being the Fimfetch version, so "site:fimfiction.net" utterly blocked the search.